# How to get video thumbnail of a video file in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I want to get thumbnail of a video file which uri or path is given. I have searched for api in windows phone developer site bt with no success. If anybody have does this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method [GetThumbnailAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227212.aspx) in class [StorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx) which intended to retrieve thumbnail of image and video files. So despite the fact that MSDN states that this method throws exception and not supported for Windows Phone 8, actually this method works when invoked with parameter [ThumbnailMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.thumbnailmode.aspx) = ListView. But I seems that using this method requires ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO_FULL.

```
    var files = await KnownFolders.CameraRoll.GetFilesAsync(); // Throw UnauthorizedAccessException without ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO_FULL
    var storageFile = files.First();
    var thumbnail = await storageFile.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.ListView);
```

Comment: Thank u mstyura for your response bt it was not working for me.my video file is stored in isolated storage.finally i have taken thumbnail at recording time only using AudioVideoCaptureDevice.

Answer (score 0):

Video Thumbnail code in c# windows phone

First we use **capturesource.completed** then after we create the thumbnail and use that thumbnail 
and we use **capturesource.Imageasync()**

And this is the only way to generate the thumbnail image from video file.

Comment: I was working on this long ago.I got something to do this.THANKS